# Viewing a material's compiled shader code in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

Whenever I'm writing a custom shader in THREE.js and I make a mistake, the console outputs a nice error message with the compiled GLSL code. It includes my code along with all the extra lines that Three.js adds on automatically:

[image]

**Question:**

Is there any way to output the compiled `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` of a built-in material? I'm using `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` in my project, and I'd like to read the compiled GLSL code to understand how it runs under the hood. I know that I can go to the library's **\src\renderers\shaders\ShaderLib\meshlambert_frag.glsl** but it has dozens of `#include` lines and does not have all the extra attributes/uniforms that THREE.js automatically appends.

I've tried to console.log the material's properties after first render, but I cannot find the compiled GLSL code:

```
var firstRender = true;

function update(){
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    if(firstRender === true){
        // Where in myMaterial is the GLSL code stored?
        console.log(myMaterial.program.vertexShader);
        firstRender = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not only view the three.js shader source code, you can edit it live in the browser using @spite's [shader editor extension](https://github.com/spite/ShaderEditorExtension) for Chrome.

Comment: Firefox has a shader code viewer in it's devtools. I also just came across a chrome extension called [spector.js](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spectorjs/denbgaamihkadbghdceggmchnflmhpmk?hl=en) which seems quite good (which I just noticed is mentioned in the other answer...woops)

Comment: Thanks, @2pha ! The FireFox shader editor is fantastic, and I didn't even have to install any 3rd party plugins!

Answer (score 2):

It's (as far as I can tell) not possible to programmatically access the final code that is uploaded to the GPU. The only place where it exists [is here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/35a26f178c523514673d992da1aece23c1cfca6e/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js#L514-L515) in the WebGLProgram class. Depending on your use-case you could do one of these things:

- use a non-minified build of three.js and set a debugger-breakpoint in the `WebGLProgram`-class (stepping through the code in a debugger is also an excellent way to understand what three.js does).
- install http://spector.babylonjs.com/ or http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/ to inspect the shader-code that is executed.